# How to get the swapNamespace flag to work with cmds file import in Maya

Tags: python, scripting, maya, mel, pymel

According to the documentation - https://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/CommandsPython/file.html#flagswapNamespace

..The command should look something like this,

```
cmds.file('E:\Stuff\ASSET.FBX', i=True, swapNamespace=['ASSET','Taco'])
```

It successfully imports ASSET.FBX as ASSET to my Outliner.
But I'm always given this error:

```
Error: The -swapNamespace flag could not find the specified namespace to swap to: "Taco"
```

Does anyone see where I'm making my mistake?
Or perhaps have a working example? I need this object renamed.
Thanks you.

Comment: What happens if you create the namespace first with `cmds.namespace(...)`?

Answer (score 0):

This error only means that there isn't elements in you set with namespace `Taco`.

If you goal is only to import your `ASSET.FBX` file with namespace `ASSET` then simply use [the `namespace` parameter](https://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2020/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/Commands/file.html#flagnamespace):

```py
cmds.file('E:\Stuff\ASSET.FBX', import=True, namespace='ASSET')
```